# StrictButton at the bottom of a modelforms

Tags: django, python-2.7, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-crispy-forms

As I find borring to repeat myself, I tought of using the Meta.fields in my helper instead of copying twice my list of fields, just to have the StrictButton positioned at the bottom of my form. Here is my form:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    self.helper.label_class = "col-lg-2"
    self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        self.Meta.fields + (
        StrictButton('Send', css_class='btn-default', type='submit'),
    )
    )
    self.helper.form_method = 'post'
    self.helper.form_action = ''

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('title', 'name', 'firstname', 'address', 'mail', 'tel',
              'mobile', 'login', 'password', 'note')
```

But this line

$ (self.Meta.fields + (StrictButton('Send', css_class='btn-default', type='submit',))

just doesn't work. It raises

> Could not resolve form field '('title', 'name', 'firstname', 'address', 'mail', 'telephone', 'mobile', 'login', 'password', 'note', )'.

Do I really have to copy my fields again in order to have the StrictButton down my form?

Comment: :D sorry, I've not tested it, but idea with unpack was write, add your answer and accept it =)

Comment: It was a good idea, it gives me the solution, why don't you edit it instead of removing it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to madzohan, I needed to unpack Meta.fields. What works is:

```
   self.helper.layout = Layout(
        *(self.Meta.fields + (StrictButton('Send', css_class='btn-default', type='submit'),))
    )
```